# chrome developer console shows different value, source view shows different value

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I am building a ecommerce site using prestashop, and the price value is changed with jquery but the source view shows different value for the price! the chrome developer console shows the same value as I see it in the site. I just dont understand this.

Comment: Please include some code and a working example, if possible.

Comment: @showdev check out my edit there is a link, search for the id: our_price_display

Comment: Barmar's answer sounds right. You won't see the change in the actual source code. Where exactly are you expecting to see the price change and are not seeing it change?

Comment: when I add the product to cart, it adds it with different value, the same as the one I see in source view not the one that I see in the product page. I think this is jquery related and I am not so good at it. The file that handles this is in awp_product.js

Comment: Please bear with me, I'm not familiar with "prestashop". I'm not finding the place the price value gets submitted. I see where the size gets submitted, but is there a specific form field into which the price gets inserted?

Comment: I see the symptom. Click on the "cart +" symbol to add the item to your cart, then hover over the cart symbol in the corner to see the contents. The total there is not the same as the price of the item. But I'm not going to try to search through lots of Javascript to find where you modify prices, can you post the relevant excerpts in the question?

Comment: I have been using open cart in the past I am familiar with it, presta shop is too complicated I cant find things, and to change something I have to change 2-3 files!

Comment: Are you sure it's not just calculating the price after submission? Like, fetched from an ID in the database or something? If so, it might not be taking the size into account regarding the price calculation.

Comment: @Barmar its ok thank you, you dont have to do this for me. If I could find it by my self I would fix it by now I think

Comment: @showdev hmm not sure, but the price it adds in the cart is the value of one attribute.

Comment: I suggest outputting the posted variables after submission. Something like `echo"<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo"</pre>";exit;` That might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: thank you showdev I am going to try something to solve this. thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sources tab of developer tools shows the original HTML that came from the server. If you want to see the DOM as it has been modified by Javascript, look in the Elements tab.

Comment: yes I see it but when I try to add the product to the cart it adds it with different price.